# Restrict user to access only one service in a namespace

Tags: service, kubernetes, roles, rbac

I have been trying to attempt a scenario where user should be able perform all the operations on the service in a namespace except on one service where he should be able to do only read operations.

Below is the Cluster Role I am using to give access to all the user in cluster level for services.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: test-clusterRole
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods/exec
  verbs:
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - replicationcontrollers
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - delete
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - persistentvolumeclaims
  - serviceaccounts
  - namespaces/status
  - pods/log
  - pods/status
  - replicationcontrollers/status
  - resourcequotas
  - resourcequotas/status
  - namespaces
  - persistentvolumes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - update
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  resources:
  - deployments
  - replicasets
  - statefulsets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - update
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  resources:
  - replicasets
  - deployments
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - create
  - update
  - delete
```

And I have created associated RoleBinding for the above ClusterRole.

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test-roleBinding
  namespace: test-namespace
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: pradeep
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: test-namespace
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: test-clusterRole
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Now, I am trying to create a Role and RoleBinding for the namespace "test-namespace" restricting user "pradeep" to read only access for a specific service "test-service" as following

Role:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
    name: test-role
    namespace: test-namespace
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["services"]
    resourceNames : ["test-service"]
    verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
```

RoleBinding:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test-roleBinding1
  namespace: test-namespace
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: pradeep
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: test-namespace
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: test-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

But, still the user "pradeep" is able to delete the specified service "test-service" for some reason. 
Is test-clusterRole permissions are overriding the test-role permissions? If so, how can resolve this issue.

If not, Please suggest a way to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ClusterRole and Role permissions are additive. The ClusterRole permissions are taking as base permissions for any namespace and Role permissions for specific namespaces are added to that.

If a user should only have access to a single namespace he cannot be assigned to a ClusterRole.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Lukas Eichler. But, I am using the cluster role to give default permissions for all the users around the cluster. When comes to namespaces there are certain services which i don't want the user to edit or delete. So, with the second Role and RoleBinding in the namespace level I am trying to restrict the permission to only ["get", "list", "watch"] and still they are able to edit service. I want to avoid the situation. Is there any way?

Comment: You should avoid giving ClusterRoles to ordinary users. Give users Roles in a namespaces.